# How to set bootstrap progressbar max-value 300?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, progress-bar

I am currently making a progressbar with max-value 300, but I don't know how to set 300 max-value. Currently it is working for max-value 100 but I want it to be 300.

I've tried this:

```
<div class="mt-3 progress"><div class="progress-striped active" role="progressbar" value="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="300" style="width:80px"></div>
```

can somebody help me out of this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't assign max-value with Bootstrap4's progress bar; which is actually just a div with styling applied to it. So we can assign (80/300) which is 26.6 as the width of the bootstrap-4 progress bar;

This is possible with HTML progress bar as shown below;

```css
progress {
  color: lightblue;
}

progress {
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  background: crimson;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: lightblue;
}

progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: lightcolor;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: orange;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background: lightgray;
}

.progress .progress-bar {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <h2>Bootstrap4 - Progress Bar</h2>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" value='80' style="width:26.6%">80 out of 300</div>
  </div>

  <hr/>

  <h2>Default HTML progress bar</h2>
  <progress value="80" max="300"> </progress>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**: background color updated for both progress bars

Comment: thank you man, I have tried HTML progressbar and its working now. and how can I change the value color?

Comment: @Nomi, Kindly check now... would appreciate if you mark the answer as selected, Thanks.

Comment: Thanks man. I need more help. do you know laravel programming?

Comment: Don't know Laravel... I am a JS, angular, react, node person who had done complete branding for a few websites